# How to aggregate rmse and cor in summarise() from tidymodels in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidymodels

I have a tibble and I'd like to calculate both `rmse` and `cor` in `summarise()`.

```
library(tidymodels)  
price = 1:50
prediction = price * 0.9
My_tibble = tibble(price=price, prediction=prediction)
```

The following code works well.

```
My_tibble %>%
  rmse(truth = price, estimate = prediction)
```

However, the following code reports an error: no applicable method for 'rmse' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')". How can we fix it? Thanks.

```
My_tibble %>%
  summarise(
    COR = cor(x = price, y = prediction),
    RMSE = rmse(truth = price, estimate = prediction))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rmse` first argument is `data`, which we get by default by using `%>%` in the first case as the lhs is the whole data `My_tibble`, whereas in `summarise`, it is not the case, either use `cur_data()` (getting deprecated) or with `pick`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 My_tibble %>%
   summarise(
     COR = cor(x = price, y = prediction),
     RMSE = rmse(data = pick(everything()), 
     truth = price, estimate = prediction)) %>%  
  unnest_wider(where(is_tibble))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
    COR .metric .estimator .estimate
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1     1 rmse    standard        2.93
```

---

Or with `cur_data()`

```
My_tibble %>%
  summarise(
    COR = cor(x = price, y = prediction),
    RMSE = rmse(data = cur_data(),
     truth = price, estimate = prediction)) %>% 
    unnest_wider(where(is_tibble))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
    COR .metric .estimator .estimate
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1     1 rmse    standard        2.93
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I wonder why you use "unnest_wider(where(is_tibble)" in this case?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "lhs" in your answer? Thank you.

Comment: @YangYang The `rmse`  returns a `tibble` output.  So by using `unnest_wider`, it unnest the tibble column to regular.  The `lhs` is left hand side of `%>%` in `My_tibble %>%rmse(` which is `My_tibble` being used as the `data` argument in `rmse

Comment: You can also use the `rsq()` function in yardstick to get `cor^2` then take the square root.